# CSS Blur filter within container without clipping

Tags: html, css, filter, css-transitions, blur

I'm having an image within a parent div transition into a blurred state when hovered over. However if the image is 100% width/height of the parent, when blurred you get a bezel of the parent's background color. So I tried making the image say 140% width/height and/or negative left/right/top/bottom without success. This method does get rid of the bezel but not until the very end of the transition, and by this strange clipping effect, which I've gathered has something to the parent container's overflow property, which I need as 'hidden' for my use (see example). Please help me figure out how to get this blur effect without the bezel AND the strange clipping at the end of the transition, and while still undergoing a transition duration. For my application purposes, the image being zoomed in 120% to 140% is actually ideal. Thanks!

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: red;
}
    
    img {
        position:absolute;
        width:140%;
        height:140%;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        left:-20%;
        top:-20%;
    }
    
    div:hover img {
        -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
        filter: blur(30px);
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
        <img src = 'https://i.chzbgr.com/full/9112752128/h94C6655E/'>
    </div>
```

Comment: what you dont want from transition??

Comment: just for the blur, but for it to blur within a one second duration

Comment: Also the background of the parent doesn't have to be red. Ideally it won't matter what color it is because you won't be able to see it. I just made it red to clearly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You need background-color: red; for div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to duplicate the image and consider a blurred version at the bottom of the one that you will blur on hover. This will reduce the bad effect of seing the background.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

#container > div {
  position:absolute;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  left: -20%;
  top: -20%;
  background-size:0;
}
#container > div:before,
#container > div:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   background-image:inherit;
   background-size:cover;
   transition:filter 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#container> div:before,
#container:hover > div:after {
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://i.chzbgr.com/full/9112752128/h94C6655E/)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution. I just changed left & top property of img to 0. Hope this will help you.

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: red;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
    
    img {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    div:hover img {
        -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
        filter: blur(30px);
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    div:hover {
        background-color: white;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
        <img src = 'https://i.chzbgr.com/full/9112752128/h94C6655E/'>
    </div>
```

Comment: That stopped some of the clipping but still shows the bezel. See the red, thats the parent's color. I don't want that, that's why I made the image 140%.

Comment: @HarperCreek I've edited my solution. Check it. I think now everything is ok.